# Correct way to create a HTML page from an empty SVG document

Tags: javascript, html, dom, svg, google-chrome-extension

I have an extension I use privately that on occasion needs turn a svg document to a html document.

If I detect that the page does not contain a body element and that the `location.href` contains the text  ".svg" (the document is a SVG document) I try the following

```
document.removeChild(document.firstChild);
var body = document.createElement("body")
var html = document.createElement("html");
html.appendChild(document.createElement("head"));
html.appendChild(body);
document.appendChild(html);
```

Which seems to work. Inspecting the page shows a standard document

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

But when I try to access `document.body.style` I get a null referance error. `document.body` is equal to `null` Fair enough I then try to set the `document.body` element directly with

```
// leading on from first snippet
document.body = body;  // line 8712
```

and I get a `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to set the 'body' property on 'Document': The provided value is not of type 'HTMLElement'.
    at contentscript.js:8712`

I just can not seem to create a useable HTML document from an empty document. 
Is it possible?

I really need the page as redirecting will remove the domain and associated session.

Comment: Do you need to completely wipe out the document in favor of a new one or can you just create new contents for the `body`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus I need to get rid pf the svg content. That is what the page starts as  `<svg ...blah blah ... /svg>` and all it contains

Comment: @aw04 Did you start from a svg document? ie the address bar has something like "http://someDomain.com/someImage.svg"

Comment: nope sorry, you're right. i get the error with an svg

Comment: As far as I know what you want is not possible.

Comment: @RobertLongson Alohci has the answer below.

Comment: @ScottMarcus he does not, that's still an SVGDocument or these days an XMLDocument. XMLDocuments support XHTML but you what you don't have is a HTMLDocument so what you create in it will be XHTML and not HTML.

Comment: @RobertLongson That is quite literally semantics. The solution wipes out the svg and replaces it with (yes) XHTML that does ultimately get parsed as HTML and produces the correct output. That was what the question was about. The OP said he needed a "usuable HTML document".

Comment: He's got a usable XMLDocument, if he tries to parse HTML he'll likely come unstuck since most HTML isn't XML. XHTML is parsed as XML, HTML is parsed as SGML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See http://alohci.net/static/Blindman67_1.svg which uses

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <script type="application/ecmascript">
      document.removeChild(document.firstChild);
      var body = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "body")
      var html = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "html");
      html.appendChild(document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "head"));
      html.appendChild(body);
      document.appendChild(html);
      var i = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "i");
      i.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Italic text"));
      document.body = body; // Needed for Firefox. Not needed for Chrome
      document.body.appendChild(i);
    </script>
</svg>
```

to put the elements in the correct namespace.

document.createElement() in an SVG document (i.e. a non-XHTML, XML document) will create the elements in the null namespace where as you need them in the HTML namespace.

Comment: Yup, the namespace was the issue. I was able to write a new DOM, but couldn't get any of the HTML to parse. You could also use `.replaceChild()` instead of `.removeChild()` and (fyi), you can create a new `DOCTYPE` with `var newDoctype = document.implementation.createDocumentType('html', '', '');
      document.insertBefore(newDoctype, document.childNodes[0]);`, not that it will do any good since the document would have to be reloaded to process it.

Comment: Thanks i have a working HTMLDocument, though now I have to create all elements with `document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml",elementType)` if I dont the elements do not get a style atribute. There are two libs and 10K lines of code so rather than refactor I assign my own function to  `document.createElement` which works, but another extension I am using fails due to the missing style attributes. Is there a quick solution? If not all post it as a question another time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I use:

```
{
    let cENS=document.createElementNS.bind(document,"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"), //For the namespace URI, there's also `document.lookupNamespaceURI(null);`.
        html=cENS("html"),head=cENS("head"),body=cENS("body");
    html.append(head,body); //Instead of `.appendChild()` for each node.
    document.documentElement.replaceWith(html); //“Only one element on document allowed.”
}
```